# Laravel: How to read GET_Parameter from URL on EACH page?

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a laravel project and want to be able to read a GET Parameter from the URL on each Page. With this optional parameter (url?color=blue) i want to switch between two differen color shemes.

This parameter should be accessable from each page. My function is already prepared and works pretty good. But of course, i won't place this function on each controller and / or view.

So my question is: Is there any posibility to place this function on a central component? Where should i place it?

Comment: Would you mind [sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68302203/edit) [the code of your "pretty good" working function](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Session**

Perhaps you should consider saving this variable in a `session`? See the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session) about this. Sessions provide a way to store information about the user across multiple requests. This seems a solution to what you're trying to achieve persisting the query parameter for every request.

**Middleware**

To answer your question: you could probably write [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#introduction) to interact with this query parameter. Though it seems counter-intuitive for your use case.

The implementation depends on what you would lke to do with the variable.